# IBM Watson Unity 3D Text to Speech not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I just started working on Watson speech to text recognition in Unity 2018.3.14f1. The problem is I can't get it to work whenever I run it, it runs but doesn't catch my voice and throws an exception that "Access token not present in response". I am new to this so I don't really understand what the error actually is. In my console I have a total of 4 errors

1. [08/26/2019 12:01:06][RESTConnector.ProcessRequestQueue()][ERROR] URL:

   > https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token, ErrorCode: 400, Error:
   >   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, Response:
   >   {"context":{"requestId":"cb016290a97a4c569c66c8c54e8c5ae2","requestType":"incoming.Identity_Token","userAgent":"UnityPlayer/2018.3.14f1
   >   (UnityWebRequest/1.0,
   >   libcurl/7.52.0-DEV)","clientIp":"196.62.166.231","url":"https://iam.cloud.ibm.com","instanceId":"iamid-4.3-6319-2d7e1b8-76674d8789-7rpds","threadId":"137ffe","host":"iamid-4.3-6319-2d7e1b8-76674d8789-7rpds","startTime":"26.08.2019
   >   12:09:00:571 UTC","endTime":"26.08.2019 12:09:00:628
   >   UTC","elapsedTime":"57","locale":"en_US","clusterName":"iam-id-prlon04-6r67"},"errorCode":"BXNIM0415E","errorMessage":"Provided
   >   API key could not be found"} UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:207)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Log:Error(String, String, Object[]) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:280)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.d__31:MoveNext() (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:593)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Routine:MoveNext() (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
   >   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
2. [08/26/2019 12:01:06][Credentials.OnRequestIamTokenResponse()][ERROR]

   > Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Array cannot be null.
   >   Parameter name: bytes   at System.Text.Encoding.GetString
   >   (System.Byte[] bytes) [0x00012] in :0    at
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.IamTokenManager.OnRequestIamTokenResponse
   >   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Request req,
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Response resp) [0x0006e] in
   >   C:\Users\owais\OneDrive\Desktop\Owais\Programming\Unity\AR Google
   >   Images\Assets\unity-sdk-core-0.3.0\Authentication\IamTokenManager.cs:140
   >   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:207)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Log:Error(String, String, Object[]) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:280)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.IamTokenManager:OnRequestIamTokenResponse(Request,
   >   Response) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/IamTokenManager.cs:146)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.d__31:MoveNext() (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:633)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Routine:MoveNext() (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
   >   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

3.[08/26/2019 12:01:06][Unity][CRITICAL] Unity Exception Exception:

> Access token not present in response :
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.JwtTokenManager.SaveTokenInfo
>   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.TokenData tokenResponse) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/JwtTokenManager.cs:169)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.JwtTokenManager.OnGetToken
>   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.DetailedResponse`1[T] response, IBM.Cloud.SDK.IBMError
>   error) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/JwtTokenManager.cs:106)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.IamTokenManager.OnRequestIamTokenResponse
>   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Request req,
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Response resp) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/IamTokenManager.cs:151)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+d__31.MoveNext () (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:633)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Runnable+Routine.MoveNext () (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext
>   (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr
>   returnValueAddress) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:207)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Log:Critical(String, String, Object[]) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:295)
>   IBM.Cloud.SDK.LogSystem:UnityLogCallback(String, String, LogType) (at
>   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Logging/Logger.cs:168)
>   UnityEngine.Application:CallLogCallback(String, String, LogType,
>   Boolean)

4. Exception:

   > Access token not present in response
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.JwtTokenManager.SaveTokenInfo
   >   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.TokenData tokenResponse) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/JwtTokenManager.cs:169)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.JwtTokenManager.OnGetToken
   >   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.DetailedResponse`1[T] response, IBM.Cloud.SDK.IBMError
   >   error) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/JwtTokenManager.cs:106)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Authentication.IamTokenManager.OnRequestIamTokenResponse
   >   (IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Request req,
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+Response resp) (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Authentication/IamTokenManager.cs:151)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Connection.RESTConnector+d__31.MoveNext () (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Connection/RESTConnector.cs:633)
   >   IBM.Cloud.SDK.Utilities.Runnable+Routine.MoveNext () (at
   >   Assets/unity-sdk-core-0.3.0/Utilities/Runnable.cs:131)
   >   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext
   >   (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr
   >   returnValueAddress) (at
   >   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

Please can anyone help? Much appreciated..

Comment: This looks like you are not able to authenticate. Can you show example code of how you instantiate and authenticate your service?